# How to rotate screens separately?

Tags: display

Is there a way to rotate an external screen separately and keep the orientation of the inbuilt display fixed?

Using OS X 10.8.5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to orient each screen separately. In fact, [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jaapstronks/4143025337/) is a link of that very thing being done.

To access the screen rotation option in OS X:

1. Launch **System Preferences**.
2. Hold down <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>⌥ alt/option</kbd> and click **Displays**.
   [image]
3. On the right side of the Display Preferences, look for the **Rotation** drop down menu.
4. Set the rotation you want.
   [image]
5. Confirm the change and quit System Preferences.
   [image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, I just tried this, but it seems this way I will always rotate both the external and the internal screen simultaneously ! I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, using the drop down for the external screen will automatically make the same change to the respective drop down for my internal screen ....

Comment: Thanks again, got it. For some reason it just always decided to swap to mirroring automatically...

Comment: Do NOT rotate your screen using command-alt-click on the Display preference pane. http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/104832/55028