# Screen rotation bug and reset

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display

Poked at the system settings, display settings, and changed screen rotation setting to 180.
Immediately after rotation setting became read only, and then after 30 seconds it crashed.

After reboot i cant'go to system setting any more, it just says to me that it cant open display settings and hangs.

NVRAM reset (options+cmd+R+P) does not reset screen rotation setting, only everything else.

So. How to do rotate display back to default? Command line options anyone?

Macbook Pro 13", 2013, OS X 10.10.2

Comment: Do NOT rotate your screen using command-alt-click on the Display preference pane. Hack/fix here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/104832/55028

Comment: The fb-rotate tool mentioned in DamienG's answer worked for me when I had the exactly the same problem.

Comment: andrey rodin which app was this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reset the System Preferences:

- Delete `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.systempreferences.plist`

If you don't see the Rotation Setting in the Displays Panel, try this:

1. Close the System Preferences if it is open.
2. Open System Preferneces
3. option-command click on Displays
4. You should now have access to the rotation settings.

Comment: No, it can't open display settings by all means.

Comment: Sorry, I read too fast. I updated my answer on how to hopefully reset the System Preferences so it doesn't crash.

Comment: deleting systempreferences.plist doesn't do anything...

Comment: You zapped the PRAM, have you booted in safe mode (hold down shift while starting up ) or logged into a different user account?

Comment: yes, i did all mentioned things.

Comment: but i fixed this by spending 1$ on app in App Store, which gave shortcuts for screen rotations.
it worked, i rotated screen to 0 deg, and Display Settings started to work.
eh.

but anyway, thank you for willing to help.

Comment: The app you purchased must be reseting some preference, but I am not sure where they are saved. In ~/Library/Preferences/ there are pref files  `com.apple.preference.displays.*.plist` where * is a hash code referring specific display. (I assume an external display). However, on my system, these do not appear to have recent timestamps despite having just done a lot of Display changes on my own system.

Answer (score 3):

Accepted answer didn't work for me but the following free command-line tool did;

https://github.com/CdLbB/fb-rotate

Once compiled (see readme) just `./fb-rotate -d 0 -r 0`

Comment: Even works on MacOS Sierra

Comment: Perfect! Worked like a charm. Thank you so much!

Comment: No longer works on Catalina, even with sudo - IOServiceRequestProbe: error 268435459.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into an issue where I could not load the display pane at all, even after multiple quits and restarts and PRAM resets; safe mode boot resolved it for me!

Answer (score 0):

I have a MacBook Pro with macOS 10.12.3, did the rotation before I read this post.  The way that I fixed it was doing a Safe Mode Restart.  Was pulling my hairs out

Answer (score -1):

I bought [Pivot - Display Rotation](https://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/pivot-display-rotation/id657194146?mt=12) on the Apple Store and it fixed the problem.