# How to rotate the touch input on an external touchscreen connected to a Macbook Pro?

Tags: display, screen, touchscreen

I am trying to connect an [external touchscreen](https://www.waveshare.com/product/displays/lcd-oled/lcd-oled-1/5.5inch-hdmi-amoled.htm) to a Macbook Pro (Mid 2015, macOS Mojave version 10.14.6). The touch input and the screen works, but by default the orientation of both of them is vertical. I need them to be horizontal.

I can easily change the orientation of the screen (following the steps [described here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/101914/373357)), but while the screen is rotated, the touch input stays vertical - so e.g. when I swipe left to right, the cursor moves up-down.

I tried searching any mentions of similar problems and I went through all preferences, but I could not find anything related to my issue. Anyone experienced something similar?

FWIW, I am connecting the screen using hdmi, and the touch input is connected via USB.

Comment: Did you find a solution? We are facing the same Problem.

Comment: @Tim unfortunately not, I had to give up.

Comment: Thank you  i think we will switch to a raspberry pi for our use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth i'd like to add my knowledge to this topic.

I've been working on lots of installations using (multiple) touch screens on macOS in the past years. It's easy to rotate a screen but to rotate the touch you need a tool for this touch to calibrate it.

By calibrating you align coordinates on the touch device to pixel positions on the display. In case of multiple touch screen installation it's even mandatory to calibrate every screen. Without it every touch from secondary screens would "land" on the logical first display.

A lot of touch screen manufacturers do not create their own macOS touch driver because the market is not deemed big enough. They either don't care at all, rely on simple mouse emulation or they have a third party driver.

The source for this driver is either the manufacturer for the touch hardware that was bought to integrate into a display or Touch-Base in UK.

Some display manufacturers like Samsung or ELO have an OEM driver by Touch Base that works for all their models. Others have individual drivers per model/series.

I'm working with Touch-Base - not for them - and they provided drivers for every touch hardware i've come across. A team of nice people that even programmed a driver for an exotic display they never saw before.

On their website you can download a tool that identifies the touch hardware and from this tool you can request a demo driver. This driver works for 7 days and allows 200 touches per start.

With this demo driver alone you could already calibrate the screens and uninstall the demo afterwards. Usually the calibration gets stored into the touch controller. So it won't be lost after uninstalling.

Or if you like all the features they provide (multitouch support, TUIO, per-app gestures, e.t.c ) you can purchase and keep the software.

[Touch Base UK](https://touch-base.com)

Answer (score -1):

Try uppd touch software.
ask g****e

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Have a look at our conduct guide https://apple.stackexchange.com/conduct the community considers “Ask Google” a bit of a put down without some context.